# dynamically render a 2d board in 3d view

Tags: c++, opengl

I am a beginner in openGL. I am currently working on a program which take in inputs the width and the length of a board.  Given those inputs i want to dynamically position my camera so that i can have a view on the whole board. Let' s say that my window size is 1024x768.

Are there any mathematical formula to compute the different parameters of the opengl function glookat to make it possible ?

the view i want to have on the board should look like this.

[image: board image]

It doesn't matter if a board too big will make things look tiny. What matters the most here is to position the camera in a way that the view on the whole board is made possible

So far i am hopelessly randomly changing the parameters of my glookat function till i ran into something decent for a X size width and and Y size Height.

my gluperpective function :
`gluPerspective(70 ,1024 / 768,1,1000)`

my glooatfunction for a 40 * 40 board

`gluLookAt(20, 20, 60, 20, -4, -20, 0, 1, 0);`

how i draw my board (plane):

```
         glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
  glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );

  glLoadIdentity();
  gluLookAt(20, 20, 60, 20, -4, -20, 0, 1, 0);

  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_sol);
  glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glTexCoord2i(0, 0);  glVertex3i(width, 0, height);
  glTexCoord2i(10, 0);  glVertex3i(0, 0, height)
  glTexCoord2i(10, 10);  glVertex3i(0, 0, 0);
  glTexCoord2i(0, 10);  glVertex3i(width, 0, 0);
  glEnd();
```

the output looks as follow :

[image: my board output image]

Comment: What have you tried? Any specific problem that you face in trying something?

Comment: So far I have been able to draw something and put a camera above. It kind of look decent. Problem is to make the rendering on the whole board i am hopelessly randomly changing the glookat parameters till i ran into something decent. Let me update my question with some snippet of my work.

Comment: [manual](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml) shows each parameter do. To determine values try to visualize (eg on a sheet of paper) where the 'board' lies, and where the camera should be. eg pass the middle of the board to the `LookAt` as `center*` and an edge as `eye*`

Answer (score 0):

Though this is written as an XNA tutorial, the basic technique and math behind it should carry over to OpenGL and your project:

[Positioning the Camera to View All Scene Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197900.aspx)

Also see

[OpenGL FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm)

> 8.070 How can I automatically calculate a view that displays my entire model? (I know the bounding sphere and up vector.)

**Edit in response to the comment question**

A bounding sphere is simply a sphere that completely encloses your model. It can be described as:

> A bounding sphere, **S**, of a point set **P** with **n** points is described by
>   a center point, **c**, and a radius, **r**.

So,

`P` = the vertices of your model (the board in this case)

`c` = origin of your model

`r` = distance from origin of the vertex, in `P`, farthest from the origin

So the Bounding Sphere for your board would be composed of the origin location (`c`) and the distance from one corner to the origin (`r`) assuming the board is a square and all points are equidistant.

For more complicated models, you may employ pre-created solutions [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083671/735425)] or implement your own calculations [[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere)] [[3](http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/034/009/ecp083409.pdf)]

Comment: Do you (or anyone) have any suggestions on how can i compute a bounding sphere for the plane i have (with y constant, equals zero) ?

Answer (score 0):

`gluLookAt` takes 2 points and a vector; the *eye* and *centre* positions and the *up* vector. There's no issue with the last parameter. The first two are relevant to your question.

I see that your board in the world space is extending on the positive X and Y axes with some arbitrary width and height values. Lets take width = height = 1.0 for instance. So the board spans from (0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1); the Y value is ignored here since the board lies on the Y = 0 plane and have the same value for all vertices; these are just (X, Z) values.

Now coming to `gluLookAt`, *eye* is where the camera is in world space and *centre* is the point where you want the camera to be looking at (in world space)

Say you want the camera to look at centre of the board I presume, so

```
eye = (width / 2.0f, 0, height/2.0f);
```

Now you've to position the camera at its vantage point. Say somewhere above the board but towards the positive Z direction since there's where the user is (assuming your world space is right handed and positive Z direction is towards the viewer), so

```
centre = (width / 2.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f);
```

Since the farthest point on Z is 0, I just added one more to be slightly father than that. Y is how much above you want to see the board from, I just chose 5.0 as an example. These are just arbitrary values I can come up with, you'll still have to experiment with these values. But I hope you got the essence of how `gluLookAt` works.